# Data annotation for DateTime type ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want to have a validation for `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { type = "date" })` so only users between 18 and 100 can sign up. Also no one should be able to input a date after today's date.

Do I really need a custom data annotation for this or is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Better to go for a DataAnnotation class with required properties like minAge, maxAge e.t.c. so that you can put your logic there like `users between 18 and 100 can sign up`.

Comment: @user1672994 I was thinking if there was a copy-paste regex solution, but yeah might have to go with a class for this one